# First n Happy Numbers

Tags: python, mathematics

I wrote a piece of code to generate a list of \$n\$ Happy Numbers, would love to see how I can write it better. More information below.

```
#a happy number is defined is found by taking a number, and adding the sum of its digits, and repeating the steps to add the sum of square
#of the resultant digits until we reach 1, if the result never reaches 1 then it is not a happy number

# example: number = 7
# 7^2 = 49
# 4^2 + 9^2 = 16+81 = 97
# 9^2 + 7^2 = 81 + 49 = 130
# 1^2 + 3^2 + 0 = 1+9 = 10
# 1^2 + 0 = 1 HAPPY number
#defining a emtpy list that will be populate as soon as we encounter a happy number
happy_numbers = []
sqdict={str(i):i**2 for i in range(10)}

#lets define our adder
def adder3(num):
    return sum(sqdict[i] for i in str(num))

#now we need to take a number and keep adding until we get a 1 or the loop keeps repeating
# lets define a function for that

def happynum (num, counter):
    i_sum = adder3(num) # storing the value from the adder fucntion to i_sum
    if i_sum == 1: # check for happy number
        happy_numbers.append(number)
        # print("The given number {} is a happy number.".format(number))
        return 1
    else: # we continue to keep splitting and adding until we reach 1 or attain infinite loop
        counter +=1
        if counter > 50:
             # print("The number {} isnt happy :(.".format(number))
            return False
        else:
            happynum(i_sum,counter)

counter = 0 # initializing a counter to keep keep track of the infinite loop if it does reach that.
# user_num = 7
for i in range (0, 1000):
    number = i
    happynum(number, counter)
print(happy_numbers[10])
```

The code above is working well for what I am trying to achieve. However, I tried defining the counter as a global variable before all the methods, but when called in the method I was not able to increment. It threw aa error "local variable referenced before assignment".

Additionally, I am not sure using a for loop in the end to generate 1000 Happy Numbers is an efficient way, it seems somewhat limiting. Would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Coding style

There is too little white space at many places, for example

> ```
> sqdict={str(i):i**2 for i in range(10)}
> ```

This and other [PEP8 coding style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
violations (most of them related to spacing and too long comment lines)
can be detected by checking your code at [PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com).

#### Unnecessary comments

There are some comments which add no information to the code and can safely be removed,
such as

> ```
> #lets define our adder
> def adder3(num):
> ```

or

> ```
> i_sum = adder3(num) # storing the value from the adder fucntion to i_sum
> ```

#### Naming

> ```
> def adder3(num):
> ```

Is is impossible to guess from the function name what its purpose might be.
I'd suggest something like `square_digit_sum`.

> ```
> def happynum (num, counter):
> ```

Here we know what the function is about, what does it *do*? Compute a happy number,
check for happy number, ...?

#### Code structure:

The global variable `counter = 0` is not used at all and can be removed.

A global variable `number = i` is used to "remember" the argument of
the inital call to the recursive `happynum` function, and the function 
(as a "side effect") appends to the global `happy_numbers` array.
This is error-prone and not very elegant.

I'd suggest to define a function `is_happy` instead, which takes a number and
recursion limit, and returns True or False. The default recursion limit can be
defined as a default parameter value:

```
def is_happy(num, reclimit=50):
    if num == 1:
        return True
    if reclimit <= 0:
        return False
    return is_happy(square_digit_sum(num), reclimit - 1)
```

Note also that no `else:` block is needed if the `if:` block 
has a return statement. This saves indenting levels.

Then you can use list comprehension

```
happy_numbers = [num for num in range(1000) if is_happy(num)]
```

or a filter

```
happy_numbers = filter(is_happy, range(1000))
```

to create an array with the first 1000 happy numbers.

Also it is a good habit to put add a "main guard" so that the source file can be
imported as a module:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    happy_numbers = filter(is_happy, range(1000))
    print(happy_numbers)
```

#### Performance improvements:

Computing the square digit sum can be made slightly faster by using integer
arithmetic only, without string conversions:

```
def square_digit_sum(num):
    sum = 0
    while num > 0:
        digit = num % 10
        sum += digit * digit
        num //= 10
    return sum
```

(This makes the `sqdict` hash obsolete.)

The recursion limit of 50 is somewhat arbitrary, and might not be sufficient for
large numbers. A possible alternative is to remember all numbers seen so far 
in a set:

```
def is_happy(num):
    seen = set()
    while num > 1:
        if num in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(num)
        num = square_digit_sum(num)
    return True
```

#### More suggestions:

Add [docstring comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to all functions.